# Prove that if $\delta(G)+ \Delta(G)+1 \geq \left|V\right| $ then G is connected

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I have been give this problem and asked to solve it in less than 8 minutes, I failed. I would appreciate your approach to the solution much more than the solution itself and any recommended exercice sources that would help me solve such problems faster.

Please note that G is a simple Graph

Comment: Consider a vertex $v$ of maximal degree. Now take any vertex $u$ not adjacent to $v$. Does it have enough neighbors so that you can conclude there is a path from $u$ to $v$?